# Can I somehow call JSTL function from JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, jstl, jsp-tags

The question is as following: when I write JavaScript inside my JSP page, using JSTL function, it renders normally, understanding everything I want from it. But to make my code clear, I want to move that JavaScript from  tag in JSP to a separate file. But when I try to call same function from the file, it doesn't work, but just appends to my page as a simple text.
Here is code example to make this more understandable.

```
...other JSP stuff

    <script>
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                $('#holder').append(
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td>item.price + ' <fmt:message key="currency.default"/></td>'
                    '</tr>'
                );
            });
    </script>
```

This works perfect for me. The actual message from the resource bundle is pulled and set instead of the fmt:message function.

But when I move the same code to a separate file, all this doesn't transform and stays plain text.

I understand, that JSP serves on the server, and all transformations with those functions is done much earlier than actual javascript is loaded.

But maybe somebody knows a certain hack to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DWR for that cause. An old framework but still holds good if that is what exactly you are looking for in your question.
http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html

DWR is a Java library that enables Java on the server and JavaScript in a browser to interact and call each other as simply as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I've never heard about this library, but as for the description on their website, this is really what I've been looking for. I'll try to dive into it and use it for my needs =)

Answer (score 1):

Running java methods or jstl functions(also jstl functions are java methods) from JavaScript is impossible. Because java methods run on server-side but javascript on client-side.

If you want to run java methods in client-side anyway you must create java applet for this. You can run java methods with JavaScript inside your applet. For detailed information see this [Java Applet Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm trying to implement everything as simple as possible, using Spring 4 and being aware of out-dated things like applets. For now I'm just created another JSP file with all my scripts which are using JSTL tags, and import it when needed